# Maximum recursion depth exceeded

Tags: python, recursion, max

I receive the "max recursion depth exceeded" error.

```
#Defining an example function here
def f(x):
    return e**(-2*x)
```

#Command
    def simpsons(a,b):
        c = (a+b)/2
        return (b-a)/6*f(a)+4*f(c)+f(b)

```
#The Adaptive Simpson's formula
def adaptive_simpsons(a,b,tol,comparison):
    c = (a+b)/2
    left = simpsons(a,c)
    right = simpsons(c,b)
    if abs((left + right - comparison)/15) < tol:
        return (left + right - comparison)/15 + left + right
    else:
        return adaptive_simpsons(a,c,tol/2,left) + adaptive_simpsons(c,b,tol/2,right)
```

However, when I print:

```
print adaptive_simpsons(a,b,tol, simpsons(a,b)),
```

I receive the error "maximum recursion depth exceeded"

Did I do anything wrong in my code, or is it really having to loop through this recursion formula many times?  And, how would I fix this??

Comment: You can try to print the value of `a`, `b`, `tol`, and `comparison` at the beginning of `adaptive_simpsons` function to see where you would've gone wrong. If the code is correct, then, as others suggested, you need to change it into iterative instead of using recursion.

Comment: Probably you shouldn't reduce the `tol` value? I guess that makes the function never reach the base case.

Answer (score 2):

Python deplorably doesn't do tail call optimization. Hence you will have to serialize your recursion.

Also for TCO to work you will need to refactor your function (maybe adding an accumulator argument) to make it a tail call.

Comment: I would guess that there is something wrong in the code. Binary search shouldn't take more than 50 recursive calls to get reasonable result. I suspect that reducing the `tol` (which I assume stands for "tolerance") is the issue here.

Comment: @justhalf This is quite probable. Nevertheless the recursion-without-TCO-problem in python persists and is a pet peeve of mine. :-)

Comment: what is TCO that you have been mentioning?

Comment: @justhalf: tail call optimization. Most functional languages do it under the hood for you, but unfortunately Python does not.

Comment: TCO is tail call optimization. Basically using a trampoline or reusing the same stack frame for tail calls.

Comment: TCO only optimises the _tail_ call, so the other one would likely cause an overflow anyway.

Comment: @gnibbler There is no tail call in his function. The last call is always a sum... That's why I wrote "Also for TCO to work you will need to refactor your function (maybe adding an accumulator argument) to make it a tail call.". I do not understand what you mean with "THE tail call" and "the other one"...

Comment: @Hyperboreus Thanks, I'm pretty much trying to write the wikipedia python code in a different way: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_Simpson's_method#Python. The kernel keeps on crashing on me, so I'm not doing something right (or their function is a lot simpler). I'm still a little stuck here.

Comment: @har.cruz1972 Better look at the C-implementation on wiki and port it to python. The python solution there is utter trash.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in `simpsons`

```
def simpsons(a,b):   
    c = (a + b) / 2  #        V-here     and    here-V
    return abs((b - a) / 6) * (f(a) + 4 * f(c) + f(b))
```

Also, since you seem to be using Python2, you should have

```
from __future__ import division
```

at the start of the module